# $.ajax weird order call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First i apologize for my future half-level in english.

I came to you cause i have a weird issue with my javascript.

Here you can see that i have this code :

```
addVoucherMaster: function (Code) {
    var btns = $('.btn-spin');
    btns.empty();
    if (btns.find('i.fa-spinner').length == 0) {
        $('<i>', { 'class': 'fa fa-spinner fa-pulse' }).appendTo(btns);
    }
    btns.css('opacity', '.5');
    $(".validation-summary-errors").attr('class', 'validation-summary-valid');
    $(".validation-summary-valid").children('ul').empty();

    var dataSend = {
        voucherId: Code,
    };
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(dataSend);

    var result = null;
    if (Code && this.addVoucherUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.addVoucherUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: jsonData,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                result = data.Data;
                return data;
            }
        });
        if (result == 'True') {
            this.payments();
        } else {
            var btns = $('.btn-spin');
            this.errorVoucher("Incorrect voucher");
            btns.css('opacity', 1);
            btns.empty();
            btns.append('+');
        }
    }
},
```

This is really bad written, but first i replace the "+" in a button with a spinner ( loader ), then i make an ajax query (async) and reexecute some code after. (all of this is executed by a data-bind="click:addVoucherMaster")

Issues start here.
When i use the Chrome debugger with breakpoints, after the 'btns.css('opacity', '.5');', my button is like i want, then the responses make me wait for 1/2 seconds, and my button stop to spin at the end.

But, without debugger, the 1/2 seconds appears before my buttons start spinning.
( so it starts and stop at the same time, we don't see anything ).

Is anyone able to help me ??

Thank you in advance,

David,

Comment: A live demo is better.  Or some html code at least.

Comment: I dont fully understood it but why you do async false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Ajax request to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.addVoucherUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        result = data.Data;

        if (result == 'True') {
            this.payments();
        } else {
            var btns = $('.btn-spin');
            this.errorVoucher("Incorrect voucher");
            btns.css('opacity', 1);
            btns.empty();
            btns.append('+');
        }
    }
});
```

The if / else structure you had was probably executed while the ajax request was still busy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but that still don't work... and, 'async: false' was supposed to do this job..

Comment: Does the same problem still exist? And could you put a number of `console.log(1)` in your code so you can see in which order the script is executed? (increment the number so you can see the difference)

Comment: Yeah that's the same problem. i've put console.log instructions after my spining instruction and in the success of the $.ajax, they seems to be executed in the good order...

Comment: Is the problem at this point that the buttons keep spinning or that they start spinning after the ajax request / data is already back?

Comment: Problem solved ! sorry for the incovenience, and thank you for your help. I've replaced async: false by async: true, and execute the next code in a request.done()... the 'async: false' freeze all the web page, the button was spinning, but we were not able to see him spinning ^^

Comment: If it wasn't my post that helped, could you post an answer to your own question with the code you ended up with?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! sorry for the incovenience, and thank you for your help. I've replaced async: false by async: true, and execute the next code in a request.done()... the 'async: false' freeze all the web page, and don't allow anything to move or any button to be clicked on, waiting for the server response.
in fact the button was spinning, but we were not able to see him do that.

Thank you again :)